# how to give action for every rule bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, lalr, bisonc++

I am trying to make a small compiler using flex and bison but i was not getting how to give action for every rule

my grammar is like:

```
     %union{
            std::string *s;
    };

%start program
%type <s> expr

%token <s> KEYWORD
%token <s> VARIABLE

%%

program : KEYWORD {std::cout << "A"; } 
| KEYWORD VARIABLE {std::cout << "B"; }
```

Variable regex is [a-zA-Z0-9]

"caps" is my keyword

if i give input as "caps lock" (caps =KEYWORD and lock =VARIABLE)
i was getting output as "B"

if i give input as caps then it waits until i enter next word and after entering any next word it prints " Asyntax error" if the next input is caps.

Issue is it waits until next input is given to print A and it still prints A if an error is present with syntax error

I was not getting what is wrong with it can someone find the mistake in it.

Comment: So, you're getting A printed, but not B?  That means you're identifying things as keywords, but apparently not as variables.  The problem isn't in the grammar — it is in the lexical analyzer, which you've not shown.  You should consider adding a newline to your printing.  (It's also unusual — COBOL-like — to use `-` as a character in variable names.  Did you mean `_` between `Z` and `0`?)  Have you made sure you can turn on diagnostic printing in the lexical analyzer so you can see the token stream returned to the grammar?  It would make life easier in the long run if you can.

Comment: how to turn on diagnostic printing in flex and i am not printing anything in lexical analyzer how to i add a newline

Comment: You have to provide the control in the Flex code.  It isn't provided by default.  However, being able to see what the lexical analyzer is returning can often help debugging grammars.

Comment: tokens are divided perfectly in flex i found it by printing to stdout for the same input

Comment: OK.  I don't code in Bison C++. or Flex C++, so I can't be bothered to convert your fragments into an MCVE ([MCVE]).  With luck, someone will be along later who can provide you different help.  If you decide to post an actual compilable MCVE, let me know (a comment to @JonathanLeffler should get my attention).  I'm glad to hear that your tokenizer is working perfectly — but I'm afraid seeing is believing.

Comment: i want to apologize i was mistaken with some errors the question is edited now actually i don't know why it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bison requires an "end of input" token to mark the end of the input and return a successful parse.  Normally, you give it this token on reading EOF (this is what lex/flex will do).  So if you enter an EOF (generally by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) after your input, it should work.

Comment: how do i stop bison from echoing the non matched input like space and new line and why does it only echoes for space and new line and gives syntax error for other non matched ascii strings.

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: Bison doesn't do the echoing of unmatched input; that is Flex's "job".  It has a default rule that echoes matched text that is not captured by any other rule (approximately `.+ { ECHO; }`).

Comment: How do i print space in bison it is printing address

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: bison itself just matches token sequences against productions and runs the associated actions -- if you want to print a space, print it in the action.  As JonathanLeffler noted, flex (and lex) will echo unrecognized characters; if you don't want that it's a good idea to use flex's `-s` (or `--nodefault`) option, which will cause it to flag an error for any unhandled/unexpected input.

Comment: what i meant to ask is as i am assigning any token value to string variable in flex if i assign whitespaces matched to string and try to print it in bison it is printing address

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: then you're probably assigning and printing a pointer rather than a string -- copy a string and print it as a string rather than a pointer if you want ta string.  Nothing to do with flex or bison per se -- just the C++ code you have in your actions.